# Rotating iPhone and changing views

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I've never played around with the iPhone being landscape, but I have a fully working iPhone app that is all assuming the user is viewing the iPhone upright. I'd like to play around with rotating the phone, and in order to do that, I did something very simple:

I added the following code to my View Controller:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"WILL ROTATE TO INTERFACE ORIENTATION: %@",orientation);

    if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    else
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,73,320,390);


}
```

and I'm getting a BAD_ACCESS error. I don't see the view load at all. So, what's the problem, and how do I properly implement the willRotate method so that when the phone rotates, I can resize all my components?

Comment: it's sort of not too much code. EXC_BAD_ACCESS is an error which results from accessing an object that doesnt exist any more. What's in your console? when exactly does it occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash is caused by this line:

```
NSLog(@"WILL ROTATE TO INTERFACE ORIENTATION: %@",orientation);
```

`orientation` is an `enum` value, therefore the format specifier should be `%i` not `%@`.

The simplest way to support rotating is to implement:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

Return `YES` for the orientations you wish to support. Do not doing any resizing in this method. Use the views struts and springs to ensure that they resize and reposition themselves correctly for the alternate rotations.

Comment: As of iOS 6, `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated; now use `shouldAutorotate`: http://bit.ly/1iu7EOn

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your logging code:

```
NSLog(@"WILL ROTATE TO INTERFACE ORIENTATION: %@",orientation);
```

The formatting specifier `%@` in your logging string is a placeholder for an `NSString` pointer.  When the app reaches this point, it looks at the orientation variable, attempts to dereference it to get to an `NSString` instance, and crashes, because it's not a pointer at all, it's an enum value.

Comment: `%@` isn't a placeholder for just an `NSString`. It works with any `NSObject` and even `CFTypeRef`s.